# Javascript replace image text links with images but ignore existing IMG tags

Tags: jquery, image

I want to replace code on page with real images instead of links to image. I can do that already based on another stackoverflow answer.

But I was wondering if there's a way to ignore anything that is enclosed in IMG tag.
Thanks!

```
$("#photos li").each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(http:\/\/\S+(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif))/g, '<a href="$1" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1"><img src="$1" /></a>')); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the lists contains a set of URLs, not links.

```
$("#photos li").each(function() {
    if(!$(this).find('img').length){
         $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(http:\/\/\S+(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif))/g, '<a href="$1" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1"><img src="$1" /></a>')); 
    }
});
```

This of course depends on what structure your HTML has.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaEpj/).

Comment: Thanks for the demo on JSFIDDLE. Works!

Comment: Yeah, my solution is dependent on the integrity of the HTML, but I doubt tags are going to be inside the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You should not just apply regular expressions to html. It is hard to understand and hard to predict which side effect it has. Rather you should use the advantage of having a fully parsed DOM tree and just pass over those elements that you care: Text nodes!

Additionally I would advice you not to write things like `"<img src="$1" />"`. If $1 contains something weird, then weird things will happen. There is no need to think about all the things that this might cause as a really simple workaround is: `jQuery('<img />').attr('src', someTextWithNotTooWellCheckedContent)`.

Here is an example on how it works:

```
jQuery('#photos li').find('*').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function(i, elem)
        {
            var matches = /(.*)(http:\/\/\S+(?:\.png|\.jpg|\.gif))(.*)/g.exec(elem.wholeText);
            if (matches)
            {
                var parent = elem.parentNode;
                var before = matches[1];
                var replace = jQuery('<a />').attr('href', matches[2]).append(jQuery('<img />').attr('href', matches[2]))[0];
                var after = matches[3];
                parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(before), elem);
                parent.insertBefore(replace, elem);
                parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(after), elem);
                parent.removeChild(elem);
            }
        });
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/B4GPt/

P.S.: You may or may not need to extend the code above by replacing `find('*')` with `find('*').andSelf()` depending on your html structure and intentions.

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks! It does seem like lot more work though... in terms of performance with the other answer, which one would be faster?

Comment: @Scott: It is hard to tell definitly because it depends a lot on the implementation of the browser's optimzation engine. But I guess that in most browsers Little Big Bot's solution will work faster. My solution works with more cases which you may consider "corner cases" but which I would not want to have. Consider http://jsfiddle.net/LaEpj/1/ where Little Big Bot's solution may be not what you want. Depends on your html structure though...